# Hide the clear button in firefox

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I use `vuetify` in firefox,

I just want to remove or hide  `type ="time"`  , `X` clear button.

But I also want to keep the type `time` .

I have search but not found anything. Sorry

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found myself ,

you just put `required` in the input html tag.

That works great for me.